# Status code of endpoint is always 401, even when logged in. Why?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have 2 endpoints: `/login` and `/welcome`

The user should only have access to the endpoint `/welcome`, if they are authenticated.

My problem is that in the browser the status of `/welcome` is always 401, even if the status of `/login` was 200 before.

**Angular**

```js
public login(): Observable<any> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + window.btoa('linda:pass')
  })
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'login', { headers, responseType: 'text' as 'json' })
}

public welcome(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'welcome');
}
```

**Spring Boot**

```java
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public ResponseEntity<String> welcome() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Welcome!");
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public void login() {}
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/welcome").hasRole("ADMIN")
                )
                .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
        var linda = User.builder()
                .username("linda")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(linda);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may consider adding an http interceptor to add a header of the logged in user.

Comment: You may consider adding an http interceptor to add a header of the logged in user.

Comment: You also may need to make a session storage

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial 
 https://www.javaguides.net/2020/09/angular-9-spring-boot-basic-auth-login-logout.html?m=1

Comment: You should include the authorization header for the second call as well.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security expression `hasRole("ADMIN")` will add `ROLE_` prefix in the authorization rule (can be configure different) so it expect the role to be `ROLE_ADMIN`, while the user manager you define is `.roles("ADMIN")` which will against the authorization rule you define hence you get the 401 Unauthorized response.

If don't want to change your role's name you can use another Spring security expression which is `hasAuthority(..)`

For more info check out the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/authorization.html#el-common-built-in)